# libpointer as input for MEX function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, pointers, mex

In Matlab, I have a a process (a data acquisition that is using calllib, but this is not important) which returns me pointers (libpointer) to a large array. I would like to use these arrays in a MEX file. If I have a libpointer X to this array, how can I use it in the MEX file?

Of course, there is the possibility to assign this to a new variable, like

```
A = X.Value;
```

But I suppose that this assignment will copy the array, what I do not want.

So my question, is there a way to use the libpointer (=the array's address) as an input argument of the MEX function and to retrieve the values from this input argument in MEX? As prhs[] is supposed to be a mxArray, I don't know how this should work.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update 2014-08-11:** minimal example code:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    (void) plhs;
    mexPrintf("%d \n",prhs[0]); // gives back e.g. "7209090"
    mexPrintf("%p \n",prhs[0]); // gives back e.g. "00000142006E0082"
}
```

And the Matlab code would then be like:

```
mex cfunction.c
pv = libpointer('doublePtr',112);
cfunction(pv)
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal example?

Comment: I've added a minimal example. It is working without errors, but I don't understand the callback when I print out the input pointer. I would rather want to use this input (here it's only a pointer to one number of the value 112) for calculations and so on in the MEX file.

Comment: Did you mean `prhs` in the `mexPrintf` statements?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo. It's corrected now. In my original script in Matlab, I used the prhs[], so this is not the solution to the problem.

Comment: Indeed that would not solve the problem. The type of `prhs[0]` is `mxArray*`, which itself contains a pointer to the actual array/object.  This is obtained by `mxGetData` (e.g. `(float*) mxGetData(prhs[0])` to get the pointer to a `single` array.  Unfortunately, there are no C/C++ functions for manipulating objects of the `libpointer` class, and there is no declaration for this type of object in C.  I think you have no choice but to call the MEX function with `X.Value` as the input.  MATLAB has copy-on-write semantics in many places, so it may actually avoid making a copy of the data.

Comment: This is quite disappointing. I thought there should be an easy way to extract the pointer address from the libpointer (either in C or Matlab), but apparently I was wrong.

Comment: I tested it out, and Matlab *does* make a copy of the array if I use X.Value (at least I see a memory jump in the task manager).

Comment: That is a shame.  It may be possible to reverse engineer the structure of a `libpointer` object to find the location of the data pointer... It's an interesting question though.